# whether this C code will compile or not?

Tags: c

will the code containing this function compile ??

```
int *f1(void)
{
   int x = 10;
   return &x;
}
```

it is compiling fine in my system but I saw an explanation for compilation failure of this code : "Function f1 returns the address of a local variable.  Since the variable’s lifetime ends after the function returns, any use of the return value produces undefined behavior."

Comment: This function will compile but dereferencing the pointer it returns is undefined behavior and will probably crash your program.

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  What is the _exact_ failure message?

Answer (score 5):

It will compile just fine. The product of the compilation however will produce undefined behavior, which means anything can happen. It can work, it can crash, it can summon pink unicorns to dance in front of your computer. It's undefined.

Fix the code, it's bad code no matter if it compiles or not.

On some compilers it may produce a warning and you can configure a compiler so it issues an error when there is a warning. So *maybe* with certain settings under certain compilers, it might not even compile.

Comment: A smart compiler might also not compile it.

Comment: Please provide some reference to support "will produce undefined behavior".  Agree it is odd code but I do not see how returning the address of a variable is UB.  Certainly if the calling routine dereferenced the pointer, it would be UB, but that is not happening here.  Does UB only occur if `__STDC_ANALYZABLE__` is defined? Ref:C11 Annex L

Comment: @chux Agreed, just *having* the code will not be UB. I assumed the function will be used somewhere and the pointer will be dereferenced sooner or later.

Answer (score 3):

The local variable expires after the function is exited. Add a static keyword and the compiler will stop complaining. The memory location of variable static int x will always be reserved.

```
int *f1(void)
{
   static int x = 10;
   return &x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

compilation will work fine. but since it is a local variable and its scope will no more after the function. so whatever  memory it reference you will get in after function return but it will be free as   point of you operating system and it will allocate to some other variable whenever memory request come to OS. so it will create problem at run time not compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable *x* is local to the function *f1*. This means that when all the instructions of the *f1* will be executed *x* won't be accessible.

This is a really bad practice which will lead to undefined behaviour because the address to the *x* variable won't exist anymore.

If you need to modify a value using a function you can always pass a pointer as a parameter:

```
void f1(int *val) {
    *val = 10;
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary that `x` is deleted. It may get overwritten  by compiler in some case but not always. This is an undefined behavior as you said, and that means it may work nicely also.